# Craft Commerce product export to CSV?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, export, csv

Does anyone know if it us possible to export products from Craft to a CSV? I can't see anything native. Sprout reports seems like it might be able to but it looks quite complicated.

Comment: Does anyone know how to export the products with their image paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an Export button at the bottom right of the products listing. [image]

Comment: Duh! Missed that completely, thank you :-)